# Apache 2 Redirect Subdomains in Given List

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a web server. Lots and lots of DNS entries for domains and subdomains are pointing at this server. Most of them, like www.foo.com, foo.com, and subdomain.foo.com, I want to keep. However, there is a certain list of subdomains for which I want to redirect.

For example, all of these urls resolve to the web server.

test.foo.com
bar.foo.com
baz.foo.com

test.foo.com is fine, we don't have to do anything, but bar and baz are on the list. That means we have to redirect them to

bar.list.foo.com
baz.list.foo.com

I can't just do a subdomain wild-card rewrite here because there is a long list of subdomains we want to redirect and a long list of ones we do not want to redirect.

Can/should I do a mod_rewrite that compares the subdomain to a list in a text file? If so, how do I do that? If not, how do I handle these redirects?

I know that I can make an entry into a mod_rewrite configuration, one for each subdomain, but that is a lot of typing, and there must be a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [RewriteMap directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to provide a list of subdomains (or other keys) that you can use inside rewrite rules.

Comment: I agree... I've used RewriteMaps and they work extremely well.  One thing I would be sure to do is to convert the text file once it's working to a berkley db file using the httxt2dbm utility

Comment: I know about ReWriteMap, but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. If it does, please provide an example.

Comment: Take a spin through the examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html then come back with questions?

Comment: Take a look at the section "Mass Virtual Hosting". I'm trying in my own server, if my tests are sucessful I will let you know.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. rewritemap can do what I want. Just all the examples of it I saw were using it in another way.